# When I switch commit from Unity Collaborate in Editor, it crashes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d

When I go to the unity editor, then go to collaborate, Unity crashes when I switch for another commit revision, why ? I have no logs, no error message, it directly crashes and I didn't found anything on the internet then can help me.

EDIT: I found logs for the editor

```
[./Editor/Src/AssetPipeline/PluginManager.cpp line 151] 
(Filename: Library/PackageCache/com.unity.collab-proxy@1.2.16/Editor/Collab/CollabToolbarButton.cs Line: 149)

Refreshing native plugins compatible for Editor in 2.89 ms, found 3 plugins.
Preloading 0 native plugins for Editor in 0.08 ms.
UPID Received '6b4a481d-7f06-4928-ac27-e359b0198a45'.
UPID Received '6b4a481d-7f06-4928-ac27-e359b0198a45'.
Obtained 17 stack frames.
Thread 0x30ed53000 may have been prematurely finalized
#0  0x000001024fbd8e in MemoryManager::Allocate(unsigned long, unsigned long, MemLabelId const&, AllocateOptions, char const*, int)
Thread 0x30ed53000 may have been prematurely finalized
#1  0x000001024f6c7b in malloc_internal(unsigned long, unsigned long, MemLabelId const&, AllocateOptions, char const*, int)
Thread 0x30ed53000 may have been prematurely finalized
#2  0x0000010049d036 in core::StringStorageDefault<char>::assign(char const*, unsigned long)
Thread 0x30ed53000 may have been prematurely finalized
#3  0x0000010049dcda in core::basic_string<char, core::StringStorageDefault<char> >::basic_string(core::basic_string<char, core::StringStorageDefault<char> > const&)
Thread 0x30ed53000 may have been prematurely finalized
#4  0x00000101397129 in CollabEntry::CollabEntry(CollabEntry const&)
Thread 0x30ed53000 may have been prematurely finalized
#5  0x0000010139953c in CollabChangeItem::CollabChangeItem(CollabChangeItem const&)
Thread 0x30ed53000 may have been prematurely finalized
#6  0x0000010140f61d in CollabUpdateAsyncJob::Exec_RemoveMatchingLocalChanges()
Thread 0x30ed53000 may have been prematurely finalized
#7  0x00000101412e60 in CollabUpdateAsyncJob::Execute()
Thread 0x30ed53000 may have been prematurely finalized
#8  0x000001013f8c1f in CollabJob::DoJobCaller(CollabJob*)
Thread 0x30ed53000 may have been prematurely finalized
#9  0x00000102d24840 in JobQueue::Exec(JobInfo*, long long, int)
Thread 0x30ed53000 may have been prematurely finalized
#10 0x00000102d24b8f in JobQueue::Steal(JobGroup*, JobInfo*, long long, int, bool)
Thread 0x30ed53000 may have been prematurely finalized
#11 0x00000102d24e56 in JobQueue::ExecuteJobFromQueue()
Thread 0x30ed53000 may have been prematurely finalized
#12 0x00000102d25168 in JobQueue::ProcessJobs(JobQueue::ThreadInfo*, void*)
Thread 0x30ed53000 may have been prematurely finalized
#13 0x00000102d240d9 in JobQueue::WorkLoop(void*)
Thread 0x30ed53000 may have been prematurely finalized
#14 0x000001032e137f in Thread::RunThreadWrapper(void*)
Thread 0x30ed53000 may have been prematurely finalized
#15 0x007fff2033e8fc in _pthread_start
Thread 0x30ed53000 may have been prematurely finalized
#16 0x007fff2033a443 in thread_start
Launching bug reporter
```

Comment: You should be able to see the editor logs https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LogFiles.html

Comment: Yes, I edited my post

Comment: No need to print the whole thing, it's likely really long. You need to look for keywords like "Exception" or "Error" and see what is happening around those.

Comment: But I printed only the piece of logs to the end in the order of the instructions

Comment: so .......... ?

Comment: So, you do Ctrl + F and look for the problems. The end of the logs is not necessarily the problem, it's just the last thing the editor was able to print.